# Grub Rescue - the laptop won't boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, grubrescue

First of all I'm Italian, so I apologize for my bad English.

Second, I have a big problem. I have a new Sony Vaio Pro 13 (so, it's an ultra-book WITHOUT the CD drive), which had Windows 8 pre installed. I needed to install Ubuntu in dual boot for university purposes. So, I shrunk the Windows partition and created a new partition, and from a boot-able USB stick I created a swap partition and an ext4 partition, and installed Ubuntu. Due to several failures, I used the Boot-repair tool, which installed the grub 2 boot-loader, from which I could start Ubuntu and Windows.

Anyway Ubuntu didn't start, it showed me an error, but this is not the problem. The problem is that, due to this error, I decided to try again (because maybe I did something wrong), so I logged into windows and deleted the two Linux partitions, creating an unallocated space, and rebooted with the USB stick. But I got stuck in the "grub rescue".

I looked in the internet, but I found nothing, because

- the booting order is FIRST the SSD drive and second the USB stick (whenI installed Ubuntu before, I loaded the USB stick from a Sony UEFI-like menu, which had 4 options, and one of them was "boot fom USB");
- I don't have a CD/DVD drive, because the laptop is an ultrabook;
- I don't have Linux installed on the drive any more (because as I said above, I deleted the partitions).

What can I do? In some days I have an university exam and I need to get to my documents as soon as I can..

Comment: Please don't put the answer in a question body and instead post answers as answers in the "Your Answer" section.

Comment: You are encouraged to answer your own questions.  Not only does it provide an opportunity for you to earn some reputation It makes it easier for others with a similar problem to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The questioner has reported they have fixed the problem

(removed this from question)

> I solved my problem!
>
> For those who has a Sony Vaio Pro 13: there's an "Assist" button on
>   the top of the keyboard. Press it while the laptop is off, and it will
>   turn on loading a completely dedicated loader and partition. From
>   there, you can access bios settings, load from usb, and do other
>   stuffs that will help you getting out of your problem. Well done Sony,
>   well done.

Answer (score 0):

First boot from the usb by pressing F11 key repeatedly.
[booting from external device](http://docs.esupport.sony.com/pc/VPCEG1_EH1_EJ1_EL1_series/EN/contents/02/04/01/01.html)

Then either install ubuntu on the partition again and choose /dev/sda for installing boot loader

or just install grub or use boot-repair

Comment: I could solve in a similar way - I wrote it on the main post. Thank you so much anyway!